# React Typescript Log in doesn't send request but re renders main component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, axios

I got a problem in react. After I press the sign in button, the axios call from the function attached to the button, sends the request sometimes to the back-end (tested to see if it is problem from spring, but with postman it works perfectly every time) but when send from front end it doesn't always reach back-end. Furthermore, in front, it re-renders and displays the introduced name and password in the URL.
Any ideas why? Also, if I insist with the calls for some time, it will magically change the url in front end and display correctly in the back end. I got a break-point in the promise, but it never reaches there. 
Below is my front-end, App.tsx, Login.tsx and Doctor.tsx.

```
Login.tsx

import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Login from './components/Login';
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import {Route, Switch} from "react-router";
import DoctorMainPage from './components/Doctor';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";


const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
          <>
                  <BrowserRouter>
                      <Switch>
                          <Route exact path = "/" component={Login}/>
                          <Route exact path = "/doctor" component={DoctorMainPage}/>
                      </Switch>
                  </BrowserRouter>
          </>

  );
};

export default App;
```

```
Login.tsx

import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import {Paper} from "@material-ui/core";
import useRouter from "use-react-router";
import appState from "../store/state";
import actions from "../actions/actions";
import axios from 'axios';
import {observer} from "mobx-react";


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    '@global': {
        body: {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
        },
    },
    paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    avatar: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    form: {
        width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    submit: {
        margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2)
    },
}));

const SignIn = (function SignIn() {

    useEffect(() =>
        {
            setPassword("");
            setUsername("");
        },
        []
    );

    debugger;
    const login = () => {
        debugger;
      axios.post("http://localhost:8080/login", {
          username: username,
          password: password
      }).then((response) => {
          debugger;
          console.log(response.data);
          history.push("/doctor");
      });
    };

    const {history, location, match} = useRouter();
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const isValid = () => {
        return username.length > 0 && password.length > 0
    };
    return (
        <>


            <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">

                <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                    <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                        <LockOutlinedIcon />
                    </Avatar>
                    <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                        Sign in
                    </Typography>
                    <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
                        <TextField onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                                   variant="outlined"
                                   margin="normal"
                                   required
                                   fullWidth
                                   id="username"
                                   label="Username"
                                   name="username"
                                   autoComplete="username"
                                   autoFocus
                        />
                        <TextField onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                                   variant="outlined"
                                   margin="normal"
                                   required
                                   fullWidth
                                   name="password"
                                   label="Password"
                                   type="password"
                                   id="password"
                                   autoComplete="current-password"
                        />
                        <FormControlLabel
                            control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                            label="Remember me"
                        />
                        <Button disabled={!isValid()} onClick={() => login()}
                                type="submit"
                                fullWidth
                                variant="contained"
                                color="primary"
                                className={classes.submit}
                        >
                            Sign In
                        </Button>
                    </form>
                </Paper>
            </Container>

        </>

    );
});

export default SignIn;
```

```
Doctor.tsx


import AppBarWithMenu from './AppBarWithMenu';
import {Paper} from "@material-ui/core";
import * as React from "react";
import PacientsTable from './Table';
import appState from "../store/state";
import {observer} from "mobx-react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import useRouter from "use-react-router";
import {useEffect} from "react";
import useReactRouter from 'use-react-router';

const DoctorMainPage = observer(function DoctorMainPage(){

    const {history, location, match} = useReactRouter();

    return (
        <Paper>
            <AppBarWithMenu/>
            <PacientsTable/>
            <Button onClick={() => history.push("/")}>
                Logout
            </Button>
        </Paper>
    );
});

export default DoctorMainPage;
```

[Username and password appears top, in the url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NvOx.png)

Comment: `displays the introduced name and password in the URL` - sounds like a GET request is being made instead of POST

Comment: from other threads that I read, the error(get instead of post) happens due to having a "/" in the url that I send a request, but the url is correct, if i send  from postman, it works no problem. The problem still persists in front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the form defined in your `Login.tsx` file is submitted.

Html forms are an alternative, older way of triggering requests in a web application. Unlike AJAX calls (like the ones that you attempted to make using axios), form submits cause the browser to load a new page, hence all your JS context is lost.

Html forms have an `action`, which is the URL where the request is executed, and a `method`, which is the HTTP method used to do the request. The `action` is by default the current URL, whereas the `method` is by default `GET` (can also be `POST`).

These forms can be used to send data with the request. These values are taken from the input fields inside the `form` tag. With a `GET` form submit, the data is sent via URL parameters. Each parameter name is taken from the `name` attribute of each contained input field.

All this explains why your app reloads the page when you click the button, because the form is submitted, causing a GET request on the / URL, with the username and password parameters in the URL. The `onClick` event is never triggered, so the `login` function is never called, because the page is being reloaded (so the JS context is gone).

To prevent this, simply change the button type from `submit` to `button` or do a [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) call on the event object received in the `onClick` event.